# Is there an implementation of RFC 4647 language matching for Objective-C?

Tags: cocoa, internationalization

I am looking for a way to select the best match among several files offered by a server, based on matching against the preferred languages list returned by `NSLocale`. I know Apple is doing something similar internally for selecting localized resources, but I have not found an API that apps can use.

I've found that Java 8 implements [RFC 4647](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4647) in its [Locale class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html), and there's at least one [Ruby implementation](https://github.com/SSDany/lang), but I'm coming up empty for iOS / Objective-C. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest you'll find are the class methods on `NSLocale` that allow you to turn a dictionary of key-value pairs into a locale identifier. Specifically, check out the [`+localeIdentifierFromComponents:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSLocale/localeIdentifierFromComponents:) method.

Comment: Thanks for the input, Dave, but I don't think this gets me any closer. For now, I am actually using the reverse (`componentsFromLocaleIdentifier:`) to break up the language identifiers and then comparing the relevant components. It wasn't terribly complicated, but I still feel like this is a wheel I shouldn't have to reinvent.